# How can I connect to MySQL server remotely using MySQL command line client (In Windows)? keep getting error 1064 (4200)

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

I'm using this method below to connect to my remote MySQL database but I keep getting this **error message** back:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u admin -p demo123-h testaurora-cluster-1.cluster-tjiy9ao2kavg.us-west-2.' at line 1

**Method:**

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME
```

The options above means:

```
-u: username
-p: password (**no space after**)
-h: host
```

last one is name of the database that you wanted to connect. 
Look into the the link, it's detailed there!

**Code entered in MySQL command line client:**

```
mysql -u admin -p demo123-h testaurora-cluster-1.cluster-tjiy9ao2kavg.us-west-2 TestTable
```

I would highly appreciate it if you can let me know what I am missing here..

Comment: You need a space after your password and `-h`, and your hostname should be complete, you are missing `.amazon.com` or something similar after `us-west-2`

Comment: @Burhan Khalid I tried adding your suggestions still not running. Any other thoughts?